THEOREM 3 in section 5.8.2 Lawrence C. Evans
Looking at the mentioned theorem in Evans book:
Let $u∈L^p(Ω)$ and $V⊂⊂Ω⊂R^n$. Assume that $∃ c=c(V,p)$ Such that $‖D_i^h u‖_{L^p(V)}<c$ where:
$D_i^h u=(u(x+he_i )-u(x))/h$ Then:
$u∈W^{1,p} (V)$ and $‖Du‖_{L^p(V)}<c(V,p)$ ; $Du$  is simply the weak derivative
First question:  if I'm reading the statements correctly the conclusion is $u∈W_{loc}^{1,p} (Ω)$ am i correct ?
Second question:  assume that "c" is independent of V, can we then say that$u∈W^{1,p} (Ω)$ ?
my reasoning is this: starting from
$‖Du‖_{L^p(V)}+‖u‖_{L^p(Ω)}<c(p)$  we can take the "sup" over$V⊂⊂Ω$  and the result is immediate, unless I missed something

Are you on "Partial Differential Equations" by Evans? If so 1) Yes, 2) $u \equiv 1$ with $\Omega$ of infinite hypervolume is a counterexample, unless they assume $\Omega$ is bounded.

@rafilou2003 yes the book is "Partial Differential Equations" and yes assume $Ω$
is bounded

@rafilou2003 Actually $u≡1$  with $Ω$ of infinite hypervolume  is not a counterexample  as $1$ is not an $L^p$ function in this case. So can we go with $Ω$ unbounded ?

Unless we're looking at different versions of the book, in my version it is assumed that $u\in L^p(V)$. If you're assuming $u\in L^p(\Omega)$ AND that $c$ does not depend on $V$, then $u \equiv 1$ is not a counterexample anymore, and I suggest you look at theorem $4$.

Correction to my previous comment: Unless we're looking at different versions of the book, in my version it is assumed that $u\in L^p(V)$. If you're assuming $u\in L^p(\Omega)$ AND that $c$ does not depend on $V$ then $u \equiv 1$ is not a counterexample anymore, but I think that $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ remains false in general. If you also assume $\Omega$ is bounded, then it becomes true by theorem $4$.
